# Does chrome.system.memory have an event listener

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have found a function to convert bytes into human readable format.

But I am unaware of the listening events in chrome to update it.

Is there a function to do so?

```
function fileSize(bytes) {
var exp = Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024) | 0;
var result = (bytes / Math.pow(1024, exp)).toFixed(2);

return result + ' ' + (exp == 0 ? 'bytes': 'KMGTPEZY'[exp - 1] + 'B');
}

chrome.system.memory.onChanged.addListener(function(changeInfo){
console.log("Memory changed .. " +  fileSize(changeInfo.availableCapacity));
});
```

My console reports the below

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addListener' of undefined
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/system_memory) doesn't list any listeners so in my opinion there's no reason to even suppose it might exist.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed it didn't so I went a head and created an interval to poll every few seconds on the chrome.system.memory.getInfo() and updated via my callback function.